# how to combine sevaral data in a variable

Tags: c, arduino

I have some data likes

```
A=2.333
b=4.478
c=2.447
d=90
e=43
```

It need to store in database . I want to store it in a pack like `“abcde”`  at a time and when I call them I can separate them each other .
but how ?

Comment: use string joins each words separate with a identification the use string .split

Comment: What are the types?

Answer (score 3):

That's what structs are for:

```
typedef struct {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    unsigned int d;
    unsigned int e;
} mystruct;

mystruct m = { 2.333, 4.478, 2.447, 90, 43 };
printf("%.3f %.3f %.3f %u %u\n", m.a, m.b, m.c, m.d, m.e);
```